# Reorder lines and columns by a specific pattern in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a tab-separated file where column 1 is either 0 or 16. If Column 1 has 16 then I need to move 2nd and 3rd column parallel to the 2nd and 3rd column where first column has 0. Below is an example.

```
0 69 24
0 69 27
16 55 27
0 85 25
16 77 23
```

to

```
0 69 24 55 27
0 69 27 77 23
0 85 25
```

I guess this can be done with `awk`, will appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should how a minimal understanding of the problem by showing what has been attempted and the problem encountered during the attempt(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
$1==0{zero[++i]=$0;next}
{notzero[++y]=$2"\t"$3}
END{for(c=1;c<NR;c++) print zero[c],notzero[c]}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
0   69  24
0   69  27
16  55  27
0   85  25
16  77  23
[JS웃:~/Temp]$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}$1==0{zero[++i]=$0;next}{notzero[++y]=$2"\t"$3}END{for(c=1;c<NR;c++) print zero[c],notzero[c]}' file
0   69  24  55  27
0   69  27  77  23
0   85  25
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -nr '/0\s/{H;${x;s/\`\n(.*)/\1/mp};d};/16\s/s/16\s(.*)/\1/;H;g;s/\`\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\'/\1 \2/p;g;s/\`\n(.*)(\n.*)\n(.*)\'/\2/;h;${s/\`\n(.*)/\1/mp};d' file
```

---

```
$cat file
0 69 24
0 69 27
16 55 27
0 85 25
16 77 23

$sed -nr '/0\s/{H;${x;s/\`\n(.*)/\1/mp};d};/16\s/s/16\s(.*)/\1/;H;g;s/\`\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\'/\1 \2/p;g;s/\`\n(.*)(\n.*)\n(.*)\'/\2/;h;${s/\`\n(.*)/\1/mp};d' file
0 69 24 55 27
0 69 27 77 23
0 85 25
```

Answer (score 2):

With Perl:

```
perl -lane '{!$F[0]&&push(@h,$_)||print(shift @h," $F[1] $F[2]")}
    END{print for @h}' input
```